# Pafy - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube, audio-streaming, pafy

I am using Python 2.7
When I do this:

> import pafy
>
> video=pafy.new("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9BNoNFKCBI")

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "pyshell#12", line 1, in module
>
> video=pafy.new("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9BNoNFKCBI")
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pafy\pafy.py", line 118, in new
>
> from .backend_internal import InternPafy as Pafy
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_internal.py", line 21, in   module>
>
> from urlparse import parse_qs, unquote_plus
>
> ImportError: cannot import name unquote_plus

Please Help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the current version.

Go to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mps-youtube/pafy/develop/pafy/backend_internal.py

Copy all, then go to your Python27 directory, go to pafy directory (should be something like Lib/site-packages/pafy, open backend_internal.py in a text editor, delete everything then paste the updated version from the git repo and save.

Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the newest version of pafy. 
Check this fix  https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/pull/134